# Traveling Salesman with WEKA

Tags: optimization, weka, traveling-salesman

While I am comfortable with optimization problems in Python (and 'R' for that matter) I am curious to know if it can be done in WEKA.

I have X,Y coordinates of several routes and I need to optimize the best overall solution.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weka is a machine learning, not optimization package. While you could try to predict the optimal solution using the machine learning algorithms in Weka, there's nothing to check that a prediction is the optimal solution or even a solution at all.

Definitely sounds to me like you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job.